# Issues enumerating and outputting items in outlook's sent items folder

Tags: vb.net, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

As the title says, I'm having issues with enumerating and outputting item in my sent items folder in outlook. Specifically I'm looking for sent tasks. It keeps telling me there's nothing in the folder, when there is. The code is:

```
   Private Sub GetSentTasks(objApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)
        Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = _
            objNS.GetDefaultFolder( _
            Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)

        Dim searchCriteria As String = "[MessageClass] = 'IPM.TaskRequest'"
        Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = Nothing
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Dim taskItem As Outlook._TaskItem = Nothing
        Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
        Dim resultItem As Object = Nothing
        Dim TTDcounter As Integer = 0
        Try
            folderItems = folder.Items
            folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
            If (folderItems.Count > 0) Then
                resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria)
                If Not IsNothing(resultItem) Then
                    strBuilder = New StringBuilder()
                    Do
                        If (TypeOf (resultItem) Is Outlook._TaskRequestItem) Then
                            counter += 1
                            taskItem = resultItem



                            'If taskItem.Categories = "TTD" Then
                            TTDcounter += 1
                            Dim listarray() As String = {taskItem.Delegator, taskItem.Subject, taskItem.DueDate, stripEstComp(taskItem.Body.ToString())}
                            taskPaneControl3.ListView1.Items.Add(TTDcounter).SubItems.AddRange(listarray)
                            'End If


                        End If
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem)
                resultItem = folderItems.FindNext()
                    Loop Until IsNothing(resultItem)
                End If
            End If
            If Not IsNothing(strBuilder) Then
                Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString())
            Else
                Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " + _
                                   folder.Name + " folder.")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(folderItems) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems)
        End Try
    End Sub
```